# openGL glaux.lib VS2015

Tags: c++, opengl

Hi I'm using openGL and doing a nehe tutorial but when I compile in visual studio 2015 I've got this error (sorry for the italian but I think it can be easily understood)

```
Gravità Codice  Descrizione Progetto    File    Riga
Errore  LNK1120 2 esterni non risolti   lesson7 C:\Users\Pasto\Desktop\NEHE\Lesson07\Debug\lesson7.exe  1
Errore  LNK2019 riferimento al simbolo esterno _sscanf non risolto nella funzione _GetRegistrySysColors@8   lesson7 C:\Users\Pasto\Desktop\NEHE\Lesson07\glaux.lib(tk.obj)  1
Errore  LNK2019 riferimento al simbolo esterno _vsprintf non risolto nella funzione _PrintMessage   lesson7 C:\Users\Pasto\Desktop\NEHE\Lesson07\glaux.lib(tk.obj)  1
```

It works on VS2013 but if I run it on VS2015 it doesn't work.
Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the properties of your project, Linker and Input, add in the Additional Dependencies this line : legacy_stdio_definitions.lib

Answer (score 2):

```
#pragma comment(lib, "legacy_stdio_definitions.lib")
```

Add this line in your hfile like:

```
#include <XXXX.h>
...
#pragma comment(lib, "legacy_stdio_definitions.lib")
```

It's work for me